# Multi-line JSON containing variables

Tags: python, json

I have a python script which I am using to generate pull requests (PR). Since the PR data is large, I am trying to use `"""` but the issue is that the variables within the `"""` are not working correctly. I have searched many links especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444130/python-multi-line-json-and-variables/42444225#42444225) one but nothing works.

```
import requests

def raise_pull_request(src):
    print('Source branch: ' + src)
    repo = 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/company/myrepo/pullrequests'
    my_uuid = '10b8-4dfa-a69a-67d1'

    data = {}
    data = {
        "title": "Demo PR",
        "source": {
            "branch": {
                "name": src
            }
        },
        "destination": {
            "branch": {
                "name": "demo-destination"
            }
        },
        "reviewers": [
            {
                "uuid": my_uuid
            }
        ]
    }

    response = requests.post(repo, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(os.environ["my_token"])}, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Still getting error:

```
Status Code 400
JSON Response  {'type': 'error', 'error': {'message': 'Bad request', 'fields': {'title': ['This field is required.'], 'source': ['This field is required.']}}}
```

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Don't use the `data` kwarg, use `json=data`

Comment: `data = {}` doesn't do anything useful; remove it.

Comment: @C.Nivs, thank you so much! It worked. Can you kindly post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `data` keyword argument, which is sending form-encoded data with your request. Use the `json` kwarg instead:

```py
from requests import Request

# wrong
r = Request('POST', 'http://blah.com', data='{"some": "data"}')
r.prepare().headers

# No json content type header
{'Content-Length': '16'}

# right, note this takes a dictionary, not a str
r = Request('POST', 'http://blah.com', json={"some": "data"})
r.prepare().headers

{'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
```